# Selecting only a specific role of users using PHP in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

We are using Wordpress and relatively new to PHP code. We are trying to code to show a list of users that are only in a specific role "agents" & "customers". Because most of all the users (like admin) are showing up and we just need 2 specific roles. How can we achieve this?

```
<?php
public function get_recipients_list() {
    global $wpdb;

    // Fetch the list of users starting from the POST request
    try {
        $this->_is_user_logged_in();
    } catch ( Exception $error ) {
        wp_send_json_error( $error->getMessage() );
    }

    // @TODO: nonce verification
    // We need atleast one character to search the user
    $search_query = "SELECT a.ID, a.user_nicename, a.display_name, b.meta_value as block_list
                        FROM {$wpdb->users} a LEFT join {$wpdb->usermeta} b
                        ON a.ID = b.user_id AND b.meta_key = '_ml_user_block_list'";

    if ( ! empty( $_POST['term'] ) ) {
        $search_term = $wpdb->esc_like( wp_kses_data( $_POST['term'] ) )  . '%';
        $search_query .= $wpdb->prepare(
            " WHERE ( a.user_login LIKE %s OR a.user_nicename LIKE %s OR a.display_name LIKE %s )",
                $search_term,
                $search_term,
                $search_term
            );
    } elseif ( ! empty( $_POST['user_id'] ) ) {
        $search_query .= $wpdb->prepare( ' WHERE a.ID = %d ', absint( $_POST['user_id'] ) );
    }

    $offset = 0;
    if ( isset( $_POST['offset'] ) && intval( $_POST['offset'] ) ) {
        $offset = absint( $_POST['offset'] );
    }

    $search_query .= " LIMIT $offset, $this->recipient_search_limit";
    $users = $wpdb->get_results( $search_query );

    if ( ! $users ) {
        wp_send_json_success([]);
    }

    $return_list = [];

    foreach ( $users as $user ) {
        $user_block_list = maybe_unserialize( $user->block_list );

        // Do not include user if blocked by receipent or self
        if ( $user->ID == $this->sender->ID || $user_block_list && in_array( $this->sender->ID, (array) $user_block_list ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        $wp_user = get_user_by('ID', $user->ID );

        $return_list[ $user->ID ] = [
            'id'     => $user->ID,
            'login'  => $wp_user->user_login,
            'name'   => wp_specialchars_decode( $user->display_name ? $user->display_name : $user->user_nicename ),
            'avatar' => get_avatar( $user->ID ) ?: '',
            'uri'    => esc_url( ( new User( $user->ID ) )->get_link() ),
            'blocked'=> false,
            'seckey' => wp_create_nonce("block-user-{$user->ID}")
        ];
    }

    wp_send_json_success( $return_list );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has its own function for that. `get_users( array $args = array() );`

So, an example could be done like this :

```
$args = array(
    'role__in'    => array('agents','customers'),
    'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
    'order'   => 'ASC'
);
$users = get_users( $args );
```

This returns users as objects, So the loop is used like this :

```
// Array of WP_User objects.
foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
    echo '<span>' . esc_html( $user->display_name ) . '</span>';
}
```

But based on your code block, you already knew that.

Hopefully this helps you somewhat.

You can read about the query parameters here : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/

*note*

If you want to use your existing code, just make a check for the role, before you push it into the returnlist array - You already have the object.

So you also has the users array of roles - Looking like this :

`["roles"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(13) "administrator" }`